# Racket: applying filter on a field of a struct in a list of struct

Tags: struct, filter, racket

Please find my code snippet below:

```
 (define (try los)
    (filter (string=? (person-name (first los)) "Mike") los))
```

I am getting some syntactical errors here. I am not sure how to apply filter on 1 particular field of struct in a list of structs. (Note: I do not want to use recursion). Can someone give me an example for the same or help me correct what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Note: los is a list of 'Person' where person is defined as a struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define lambda function in filter:

```
(filter 
   (lambda(x) (string=? (person-name x) 
                        "Mike")) 
   los)
```

Such lambda functions are very useful and often used with 'map', 'ormap', 'andmap', 'filter', 'for-each', 'apply', 'memf', 'findf', 'foldl', 'foldr' etc to act on each member of the given list. See [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) for many examples (search for lambda).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to make a helper function, `mike?`, that accepts a person struct `s` and checks whether the name is `"Mike"`.

```
(define (mike? s)
  (string=? (person-name s) "Mike")

(define (try los)
    (filter mike? los))
```