# Racket: how to apply filter on a field of a struct in a list of struct

Tags: struct, lambda, filter, racket

My task is to write a function, inYear, which takes a number called year, and a list of event structures and produces a new list where each element is an event structure which occurred during year. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024730/racket-applying-filter-on-a-field-of-a-struct-in-a-list-of-struct) and tried defining a lambda function within the filter. See my event definitions/list, function and test below. The test fails and no elements get filtered out, it just returns the original list. What am I doing wrong?

```
(struct event (name day month year xlocation ylocation) #:transparent)

(define e1 (event "new years" 1 "Jan" 2021 0 0))
(define e2 (event "valentines" 14 "Feb" 2021 2 2))
(define e3 (event "my birthday" 6 "Mar" 2021 10 10))
(define e4 (event "tyler's birthday" 10 "Sep" 2020 20 20))
(define l1 '(e1 e2 e3 e4))

(define (inYear year events)
  (filter (lambda (e) (equal? (event-year e) year)) events))

(check-expect (inYear 2021 l1) '(e1 e2 e3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition `l1` evaluates to a list of symbols not a list of structs.

```
'(e1 e2 e3 e4) = (list 'e1 'e2 'e3 'e4)
```

You can convert the definition and the test output to be `(list e1 e2 e3 e4)` and `(list e1 e2 e3)` respectively.

Alternatively, you can use a quasi-quote-unquote combination like:

```
`(,e1 ,e2 ,e3 ,e4)
```

But this is less idiomatic for simply defining a list of structs.