# Racket - How to produce a list where each element contains only a certain field from a list of structures?

Tags: list, struct, filter, racket

I'm writing a function, inDayRange, which takes two days (a start day and an end day) and a list of event structures and produces a new list where each element in the new list is **only the name** of all events which occurred between the two days (including start day and end day) but in any month or year.

```
(struct event (name day month year xlocation ylocation) #:transparent)

(define e1 (event "new years" 1 "Jan" 2021 0 0))
(define e2 (event "valentines" 14 "Feb" 2021 2 2))
(define e3 (event "my birthday" 6 "Mar" 2021 20 20))
(define e4 (event "tyler's birthday" 10 "Sep" 2020 23 23))

(define l1 (list e1 e2 e3 e4))

(define (inDayRange start end events)
  (filter (lambda (e) (>= end (event-day e) start)) events))
```

I have the function written to filter what events occurred between the two days, but it returns a list of event structures. How do I produce a list of just the names of the events?

Comment: Hints: How would you get the name of the event from an `event` struct? Do you know how to use `map` to transform the elements of a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Racket: how to apply filter on a field of a struct in a list of struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427720/racket-how-to-apply-filter-on-a-field-of-a-struct-in-a-list-of-struct)